# Python and MySQLDB connection to another server on the network

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing a Python app that runs on my windows machine and I am trying to connect to my MySQL server on a linux box. I've had no trouble writing code locally on my linux box in python and connecting to the MySQL db, but when I try and connect over my local network it fails.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.0.100", user="root", passwd="password", db="db")
```

I get:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.100' (10061)")

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your linux machine? Or is root allowed to connect to your mysql from any other host than localhost?

Comment: Doubt this is anything to do with windows. Check your permissions on the mysql box, they can be by domain. Oh and is that a static IP, can you reach it from the windows box?

Comment: And set up another user to do it,. Exposing root access willy nilly is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a MySQL configuration issue.

Make sure MySQL is listening on 192.168.0.100 (or 0.0.0.0) and not on 127.0.0.1. Do this by setting the [bind-address option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address).

For security considerations, instead of using `root`, it is recommended to create a separate user to connect remotely with. Then grant it access from a specific IP(-range): `GRANT ... TO username@'192.168.0.%'`, assuming your local IP is in 192.168.0.0/24.

One other thing to check is to make sure your firewall allows access to/from port 3306.

Comment: Thanks all, i used ufw to allow access on port 3306 and set bind-address to 192.168.0.100, from 127.0.0.1. Rebooting now.

Comment: Please don't use root. :(. Create a user for the application / role. Let that access the db remotely.

Comment: Thanks Rob Wouters and others, so in summary i did:
  ufw allow on port 3306
  in mysql used GRANT, to allow the user from the remote IP
  added the port to my mysql connect

I will create a new user,  changed bind-address to 192.168.0.100

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I agree. I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Will add a new user also! Thanks all

Comment: Glad we are all rowing in the same secure direction. :)